# How can I kill all other entities except for tamed wolves and players?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I use this command `kill @e[type=!Player]` to kill everything except for players, but does anyone know how to make it not kill tamed wolves/dogs as well as players?

Answer (score 0):

Similarly to how you are doing it for player. Both wolves and dogs have the same entity name, "Wolf", so use this:

```
/kill @e[type=!Wolf]
```

Note: Keep in mind that this targets everything except wolves, which means that it kills all players (which was what OP's original question asked before the eidt).

Comment: how do you do it for wolfs and players

Comment: @alixey999 That's not what you asked, and unfortunately has a completely different and more complicated answer.

Comment: sorry i meant both of them but thx lot anyway

Comment: @Frank Ah, ok. Didn't see the edit.

Comment: Feel free to dispute the downvotes, but that doesn't belong in your answer, I'm afraid.

Comment: @Frank Although OP knows, I feel the message should be left in there so people in the future know that this will also kill players (which is what OP's original question was asking for). Killing all players can be a pretty nasty mistake, and it's likely that, since the question was edited, people will now find this when looking for how to avoid killing all players. I don't care that much about the 1 downvote, but I've added the message back in as more of a warning than a complaint. Also cutting the first sentence seems unnecessary.